# why did console.log seem to cause memory leaks in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, v8

I have a function `a` where there is a function `b` that references `foo` in its closure.

```js
class Foo {}

function a() {
  const foo = new Foo()
   const b = () => {
        foo // referencing `foo`
    }
    b()
};

a() // no memory leaks
```

after I executed `a`, there are no memory leaks for `Foo`.

I also tweaked it slightly. Still, no memory leaks for the following examples.

```js
class Foo {}

function a() {
  const foo = new Foo()
   const b = () => {
        if(foo === 'foo') {
            
        }
    }
    b()
};
a() // no memory leaks
```

```js
class Foo {}

function a() {
  const foo = new Foo()
   const b = () => {
        console.log(foo.lol)
    }
    b()
};
a() // no memory leaks
```

But as soon as I logged out `foo`, it causes memory leaks.

```js
class Foo {}

function a() {
  const foo = new Foo()
   const b = () => {
        console.log(foo)
    }
    b()
};
a() // memory leaks
```

[image]

My question is why `console.log(fii)` leaks but referencing `foo` in other ways or log out its property `console.log(foo.lol)`

I tested these in Chrome 103 DevTool console.

Comment: what makes you think there's leaks? a memory leak is a very specific issue - you have not demonstrated anything more than results of javascript engine code optimisation in my opinion. In the last example, the engine needs to keep a ref to `Foo`, since it is being used on the console - all other code is so trivial, class Foo can be optimised away - it literally plays no part in anything - at least, that's my opinion

Comment: It's not a leak, it's a use of the object. Used objects naturally can't be freed. See the duped question for more details.

Comment: @jmrk but isn't `foo` also used objects in any other examples, e.g. `if(foo === 'foo')` and ` console.log(foo.lol)`? why is that only `console.log(foo)` would prevent it from being collected?

Comment: `console.log(foo)` hands a pointer to `foo` to the console. The console keeps it alive, so that you can inspect it. The closure `b` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: interesting... but `console.log(foo.lol)` doesn't point to `foo` and it doesn't keep `foo` alive?